# How to have setInterval start at button press without breaking clearInterval inside function?

Tags: javascript, html, button, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a setInterval that draws my snake game, and everytime the snake "eats" I have a clearInterval and then the setInterval var with adjusted speed. The original setInterval starts on load. How can I make it start with the press of a button?

My attempts at placing the setInterval inside the button and using functions have worked in making the button start the setInterval, but it always breaks my clearInterval inside the draw function.

```
<button onclick="">Start game</button>
```

```
if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y){
            food = {
                x : Math.round(Math.random()*(cvsWidth/snakeWidth-1)),
                y : Math.round(Math.random()*(cvsHeight/snakeHeight-1))
            };
            score++;
            if (speed >= 40) speed = speed-3;
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = setInterval(draw, speed);
        }else{

            //Remove last
            snake.pop();
        }

var speed = 140;

var interval = setInterval(draw, speed);
```

Comment: your button doesn't do anything. [mcve] please.

Comment: I know that, I have left it empty because I can't figure out what to put there. I'm wondering what to do with it.

Comment: What exactly is inside your `draw` function? If it's everything that is above - you're redeclaring speed and interval each time it's called.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using it to speed up the snake by changing the setInterval. Didn't think it would be necessary to add more than this code, and not putting something inside button since I didn't want to over complicate it since I suspected it really was quite simple. I am very new at this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By setting the `onclick` attribute of your button to `start()` causes `start` to be called when you click the button.

I also declare `interval` as a global variable since I think you need it to be global.

Then when start gets called then the interval gets started and the id of the interval is put into `interval`

```js
var speed = 500;

function draw() {
  console.log("Running")
}


var interval;
function start() {
  //Prevent start from running twice.
  if(interval != null) return;
  interval = setInterval(draw, speed);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="start()">Start game</button>
```

Comment: Clicking the button twice will overwrite the interval variable preventing it from being cleared.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes sorry, I accidentally submitted the answer before it was ready. I've fixed that not.

Comment: @Quentin fixed now

Comment: That works for my purposes:) I really learn best from example, thank you!